# How to put rate limit rules for each different user in django

Tags: python, django, rate-limiting

I'm trying to put a rate limit for each different user when they are trying to access a view. Here is my code:

```
class Profil(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

models.py

```
@login_required
def flights(request):
    rate=str(Profil.objects.get(user=request.user).rate)
    is_ratelimited(request, key='get:user', rate=rate+'/m')
    ....
```

But when I to a get on this view I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lucasbouvarel/Documents/testBCM/api/flights/views.py", line 32, in flights
    is_ratelimited(request, key='get:user', rate=rate+'/m')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ratelimit/utils.py", line 109, in is_ratelimited
    parts = (fn.__module__, fn.__name__)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

What am I doing wrong?
Do you have better idea to do I want?

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback?

Comment: Yes sorry, i've done it

Comment: fn kwargs for is_ratelimited exepected, which is currently None. https://github.com/jsocol/django-ratelimit/blob/v2.0.0/ratelimit/utils.py#L103

Comment: Check the documentation https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#is_ratelimited

Comment: Ok si i need to specify a group, i've done it, but i still can't pu a rate limit for each user, it doesn't work

Comment: here is my new code : is_ratelimited(request, key='get:request.user', rate='3/m',group=str(self.request.user)))

Answer (score 0):

I've tried in a different way but it still doesn't work...

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class MyView(RatelimitMixin, View):
    ratelimit_key='user'
    ratelimit_rate='10/m'
    ratelimit_block=True
    ratelimit_method='GET'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        rate=str(Profil.objects.get(user=self.request.user).rate)
        rate=str(Profil.objects.get(user=self.request.user).rate)
        print(is_ratelimited(request, key='get:Profil.user', rate=str(rate)+'/m',group=str(request.user)))
```

I don't have any error and I get an httpResponse, but if the account user rate limit is 5 for example, he will be able to do 10 (as written in the MyView class).
Do you have idea to put a specify rate limit for each different user.
Thank you so much

Comment: Please [edit yoyr question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58643875/edit) and add the relevant information into it. This is not an answer to your question